# How can i pull out input variables that is in def, to print function that in main?

Tags: python, variables, input

[image]

```
def inputs():
  key = input("What is your name?: ")
  value = input("What's your bid? ")
  choice = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'.")

print("Welcome to the secret auction program.")
inputs()
print(key, value, choice)
```

i want to repeat input() in main screen. So i made new function which is named 'inputs'. But my code doesn't work :( How can i make this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `return`.

```
def inputs():
    return [input("What is your name? "), 
            input("What's your bid? "), 
            input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'.")]

print("Welcome to the secret auction program.")
x = inputs()
print(x[0])
```

Another way is to use `global` keyword.

```
def inputs():
    global key, value, choice
    key = input("What is your name?: ")
    value = input("What's your bid? ")
    choice = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'.")

print("Welcome to the secret auction program.")
inputs()
print(key, value, choice)
```

Comment: Wow, that is another solution. I understood your code thank you!

Answer (score 0):

key, value and choice are local variables in the function and are therefore not available outside.  The normal way to do this is to return the variables from the function and capture them outside.

```
def inputs():
  key = input("What is your name?: ")
  value = input("What's your bid? ")
  choice = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'.")
  return key, value, choice

print("Welcome to the secret auction program.")
key, value, choice = inputs()
print(key, value, choice)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I resolve my problem and understood what was wrong! :)